# I want my tkinter images to come up every 4 seconds not all at once

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey what I want is for the same image to pop up very 4 seconds at a different location. At thte moment all the photos just pop up at once. I have tried to add time.sleep to the for loop but all the photos pop up at once any ways. Please try out my code and virtually show me how to fix, as I'm very new to python. Thanks

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from os import walk, getenv, system
from shutil import copyfile
import subprocess
import requests, subprocess, os, tempfile
import os
import tkinter.messagebox
import time


# This is the fuction that makes the original photo and is what root.after calls to later on in the code. 
def ShowAnotherWin(i):
    win = Toplevel()
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:/Users/capture.PNG'))
    win.geometry(i)
    canvas =Canvas(win, width=420, height=560)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image= image, anchor=NW)
    canvas.pack()
    win.overrideredirect(1)
    win.mainloop() 




# This is the list it, it consists of different y and x interpects point and will be combined with the showanotherwin to makee a unique image pop up.

YourImageList = ['420x544+0+0',  
  time.sleep(1)
 '420x544+200+600',
  time.sleep(88)
 '420x544+1300+100',
 '420x544+1500+800',
 '420x544+900+500',
 '420x544+500+75',



]

# this code right here takes all the elements in the list and combines it with the showanotherwin. It then displays on screen.
root = Tk()
for i in YourImageList:
    root.after(0, lambda i=i: ShowAnotherWin(i))
    # time.sleep(1)>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> leads to all the photos poping up with the only, effect being the duration of the photos poping up. Please help!!

# this right here is just making another photo by itself dont worry about it.   
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:/Users/capture.PNG'))
root.geometry('420x544+750+200')
canvas = Canvas(root, width=420, height=560)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image= image, anchor=NW)
canvas.pack()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way is:

```
for i, x in enumerate(YourImageList):
    root.after(i*4000, lambda x=x: ShowAnotherWin(x))
```

Another way is call `after()` inside `ShowAnotherWin()`:

```
def ShowAnotherWin(i=0):
    if i < len(YourImageList):
        win = Toplevel()
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/capture.PNG')
        win.geometry(YourImageList[i])
        canvas =Canvas(win, width=420, height=560)
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, image= image, anchor=NW)
        canvas.pack()
        canvas.image = image # need to keep a reference to image
        win.overrideredirect(1)
        #win.mainloop()  # no need to call mainloop() here
        root.after(4000, ShowAnotherWin, i+1)

...

ShowAnotherWin()
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically arm them all to show up after 0 milliseconds delay here `root.after( 0 ,...`

```
for i in YourImageList:
    root.after(0, lambda i=i: ShowAnotherWin(i))
```

Comment: Hey Boris thanks for the reply, when I add  (600, lambda i=i ShowAnotherWin(1)) it does.... look at the last bit of code remember I said this makes another photo keep that in mind So  when I add 600 only that last bit of code  (photo)  delays as it is separate from. But all the rest which is in the LIST still come at once.